# Postfix is not sending the mails if Message body and Header is not same

Tags: postfix

I am using postfix to send an attachment to my mail . The postfix works fine when i used the below command

`echo TodayData | mail -s TodayData xyz@abc.com -A /a/ainside/sendmail.txt`

But when i changed the command like this

`echo TodayData | mail -s DailyDataReport xyz@abc.com -A /a/ainside/sendmail.txt`

It is not sending mail but i can see the mail was sent in `cat /var/log/mail.log` . But i am not receiving anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you see in your logs that Postfix sends the mail, the problem isn't with your Postfix configuration. Probably the mail just gets silently filtered as SPAM on the receiving MTA. Check junk mail settings and possibly whitelist the sender address.

BTW, wouldn't `cat /a/ainside/sendmail.txt | mail -s DailyDataReport xyz@abc.com` look less like a spam than the current message with an extremely short body? Is there some reason it must be an attachment?

Comment: Thanks @Esa jokinen . Yeah i want it to be an attachment because i am sending csv file .

Comment: And also i checked in SPAM too but didnt find anything.

Comment: See the logs on the destination server. _Silently_ discarded messages won't appear even on spam folder. The question doesn't include any information on that MTA, and clearly the problem isn't with this MTA.